# No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Trying to add the Google Token Validation to asp.Net Core 2.2 API but getting this error when Controller is marked as `[Authorize]`

The goal is to secure some Web API functions by validating the `Access_Token` from request header.  The Access Token is generated from Google OAuth on the client side and needs to be passed to API with each request.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "[Client ID]";
        options.ClientSecret = "[Client secret]";
    });
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and
>   there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Answer (score 0):

[According to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.2#google-authentication) you don't need to specify `AuthenticationScheme` for Google authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options  =>  
{  
   ...
});
```

because value of `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` is `OpenIdConnect` but Google expected `Google`. You can use `GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`

Comment: Removed the (OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) and still getting the same error.
InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Comment: Changed to Following
            services.AddAuthentication(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Google";
                cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Google";
            })
            .AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "...";
                options.ClientSecret = "...";
            });

Now after running the VS Project, it crashes right after running with the following error:

The program '[34716] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Also try `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

Comment: I didn't run without IIS Express.  Also used [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] and still the same error

Comment: The same error like in the question or like in the comment? Then try to run it without iisexpress. Or try to remove code from comment and just use [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]. See an example [here](https://github.com/AnkitSharma-007/ASPCore.GoogleAuth)

Comment: It's really strange.  Uploaded the project to the following path.  Is it possible to take a look?  I am afraid missing something else.
http://premierapp.com/download/Google Auth.zip

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but I faced the exact same issue and this is how I solved it.

Hope it helps!

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(context =>
{
    context.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    context.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(context =>
{
    context.SaveToken = true;
    context.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    context.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com";
    context.Audience = "<your-client-info>.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    context.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = "accounts.google.com"
    };
}).AddGoogle(context =>
{
    context.ClientId = "<your-client-info>.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    context.ClientSecret = "<your-client-secret>";
});
```